# Loop through Database table and get all values of each record in turn

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba

I need to get all the values of each record in a table, this is so I can then add them to a text file log, a record per line, and then delete them from the database. I'm new to this and have searched how to add SQL query results to an array or a generic list, but I don't fully understand them.

All I have so far is:

```
Private Sub btnClearAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearAll.Click
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Application Programming\Project\Issue Logger\Database\IssueLoggerDB.accdb"
        Dim strSQl = "TRUNCATE TABLE CurrentJobs"

        Dim commandInsert As New OleDbCommand
        commandInsert.CommandText = strSQl
        commandInsert.Connection = conn
        commandInsert.Connection.Open()
        commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub
```

This is for a Uni project, and above is how we have been to shown to do it, however nothing I have found while researching looks similar.

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` irrevocably erases all rows from your table. You may wish to consider doing `SELECT * FROM CurrentJobs` first if you want to push that information to a log file.

Comment: I was planning on having the select all first, then after the file write is done in the for loop run the truncate.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this procedure:

```
Private Sub DataTableToTextFile()
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Application Programming\Project\Issue Logger\Database\IssueLoggerDB.accdb"

    Using conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        conn.Open()
        'Change the query. It's not a good practice to use '*' in your select queries. Please, use the column names instead.
        Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CurrentJobs", conn)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt)

        'Change the path to your desired path
        Dim exportPath As String = "C:\Logs\"
        Dim exportFileName As String = "log.txt"

        'If directory does not exists, create it
        If Not Directory.Exists(exportPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(exportPath)
        End If

        'Write data into the text file
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(exportPath + exportFileName)
        Try
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                sb = New StringBuilder
                For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                    sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName))
                Next
                writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If Not writer Is Nothing Then writer.Close()
        End Try

        'Finally clean database table
        Dim strSQl = "Delete From CurrentJobs"
        Dim commandDelete As New OleDbCommand(strSQl, conn)
        'execute
        commandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'close connection
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```